# How to add spaces between columns of a well-structured fixed-width text file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a text file with columns spaced by a fixed width. An excerpt of what file looks like would be

```
| OOOO     OO   OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO|
|    8      0   0                         |
|    9      1   8                         |
|   12     28   18                        |
|  108     16   250                       |
```

I want to add spaces between the second and third columns so instead of 3 spaces, there'll be 10 spaces between them. It'd look like this:

```
| OOOO     OO          OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO|
|    8      0          0                         |
|    9      1          8                         |
|   12     28          18                        |
|  108     16          250                       |
```

In order to do so, I tried:

```
awk '{print "  "$1"    "$2"          "$3 }' FILENAME
```

This command does add the spaces but the text gets misaligned. As it is, the text follows a right-side alignment for columns 1 and 2, and a left-side alignment for column 3. But after I use the `awk`command, the text gets messy.

How can I add the spaces without interfering with text alignment?

Comment: instead of using `print`, use `printf` with the correct format.

Comment: How come? Would I have to write a loop so the command would be applied to all rows? I'm only asking because I can't really make sense of your comment. I'm a beginner at Shell.

Comment: The original whitespace is discarded during field splitting, so you need to restore the justification in your script. `$1`, for example, is just `8`, not `___8` (`_` in place of spaces).

Comment: That first line is going to be a drag as it has 4 fields and the others 5 unless `FIELDWIDTHS`  is used.

Comment: Are the `|` and `0` really part of your file? If so, `$1` is the pipes, not your first column.

Comment: Also, at the moment this is purely an `awk` question; the shell isn't involved beyond starting `awk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the given format, you can do:

```
awk '{printf("%4s%7s%10s%s\n", $1, $2, " ", $3)}' FILENAME
```

(I assume that vertical lines are not part of you file, but added for illustrative purposes.)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you. 

One last question. How should I go about substituting the old formatted text by the name one in my file?

Comment: You're right. The vertical line was my attempt to show the boundaries of my file.

Comment: I should say I got to add the newly formatted table to a file with a different name, but not the same. But this is minor tweaking I gotta do to. Your answer did solve the problem so I'm going to accept as the correct answer.

Comment: To substitute the original file, try `awk '{printf("%4s%7s%10s%s\n", $1, $2, " ", $3)}' oldfile > newfile; mv oldfile oldfile.sav; mv newfile oldfile` (if I correctly understand what do you want)

Comment: You understood it correctly and that's exactly what I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{printf "%-23s%s\n",substr($0,1,16),substr($0,17)}' file
| OOOO     OO          OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO|
|    8      0          0                         |
|    9      1          8                         |
|   12     28          18                        |
|  108     16          250                       |
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative in `sed`, you could capture each column as a fixed-width string including preceding space rather than as a word, which also has the advantage that your column data can contain spaces, then re-emit with inserted spaces. I'm sure you can do the same in awk...

```
sed 's/\(.\{5,5\}\)\(.\{6,6\}\)\(.\{4,100\}\)/\1\2      \3/'
```